# scipy large sparse matrix

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to use large 10^5x10^5 sparse matrices but seem to be running up against scipy:

```
n = 10 ** 5
x = scipy.sparse.rand(n, n, .001)
```

gets

```
ValueError: Trying to generate a random sparse matrix such as the
    product of dimensions is greater than 2147483647 - this is not
    supported on this machine
```

Does anyone know why limit is there and if I can avoid it? 
(fyi, I'm using a macbook air with 4gb memory and the enthought distribution)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a limitation which results from the way `scipy.sparse.rand()` is implemented.  You can roll your own random matrix generation to circumvent this limitation:

```
n = 10 ** 5
density = 1e-3
ij = numpy.random.randint(n, size=(2, n * n * density))
data = numpy.random.rand(n * n * density)
matrix = scipy.sparse.coo.coo_matrix((data, ij), (n, n))
```