# Multiplying large sparse matrices in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I would like to multiply two large sparse matrices.  The first is 150,000x300,000 and the second is 300,000x300,000.  The first matrix has about 1,000,000 non-zero items and the second matrix has about 20,000,000 non-zero items.  Is there a straightforward way to get the product of these matrices?

I'm currently storing the matrices in csr or csc format and trying `matrix_a * matrix_b`. This gives the error `ValueError: array is too big`.

I'm guessing I could store the separate matrices on disk with pytables, pull them apart into smaller blocks, and construct the final matrix product from the products of many blocks.  But I'm hoping for something relatively simple to implement.

EDIT:  I'm hoping for a solution that works for arbitrarily large sparse matrices, while hiding (or avoiding) the bookkeeping involved in moving individual blocks back and forth between memory and disk.

Comment: What shape should the result have?

Comment: @miro: 150,000 by 300,000. But I expect the product will still be sparse.

Answer (score 6):

Strange, because the following worked for me:

```
import scipy.sparse
mat1 = scipy.sparse.rand(150e3, 300e3, density=1e6/150e3/300e3)
mat2 = scipy.sparse.rand(300e3, 300e3, density=20e6/150e3/300e3)
cmat1 = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix(mat1)
cmat2 = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix(mat2)
res = cmat1 * cmat2
```

I'm using the latest scipy. And the amount of RAM used by python was ~3GB

So maybe your matrices are such that their product is not very sparse ?

Comment: The first call to sparse.rand above gives me "ValueError: Trying to generate a random sparse matrix such as the product of dimensions is greater than 2147483647 -  this is not supported on this machine."  This machine is running 32 bit Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @DanB: the scipy.sparse.rand error is a known problem (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671150/scipy-large-sparse-matrix)] for a work around.

Comment: I think the problem is the 32bitness of your machine. The memory usage of your current matrix multiplication problem is a few gigs, so it is very easy to hit the 32bit limit of the memory allocation. So if you are stuck with 32bit machine, you'll have to do block-by-block or disk based multiplication, I think

Comment: @sega_sai:  That was what I was expecting to do anyway (though I didn't realize that I should be able to handle this on a 64 bit machine.)  My deeper question was "what's the most straightforward way to do block-by-block or disk based multiplication."  I'd like avoid the bookkeeping involved in switching blocks back and forth between memory and disk.

Comment: @DanB - Did you manage to do the multiplication eventually? how did you do that?